# How to remove duplicate fields in Redshift when the only difference is an incremental date field?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

See example table where the only difference in rows for dates 1/3 to 1/5 is the date field.

```
Date, ID, State, Amount
1/1/2017, 123, A, 1
1/2/2017, 123, B, 1
1/3/2017, 123, C, 1
1/4/2017, 123, C, 1
1/5/2017, 123, C, 1
1/6/2017, 345, B, 1
```

How to delete the duplicate rows for columns ID, State, Amount, so it looks like this?

```
Date, ID, State, Amount
1/1/2017, 123, A, 1
1/2/2017, 123, B, 1
1/3/2017, 123, C, 1
1/6/2017, 345, B, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select    min(date) as date, id, state, amount
from      some_table_name_you_never_disclosed
group by  id, state, amount;
```

BTW, `date` is a SQL92 reserved keyword, so you may want to alter that column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table and store to be deleted duplicate records as

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
AS
SELECT DATE,
       ID
FROM (SELECT DATE,
             ID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,State,Amount ORDER BY DATE ASC) AS rnk
      FROM your_table_name)
WHERE rnk > 1
```

Then use delete statement as

```
DELETE
FROM your_table_name USING temp
WHERE your_table_name.date = temp.date
AND   your_table_name.id = temp.id
```